# When to thunk to remove type error in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

The following code displays an mismatch error for the `val refl : ('a, 'a) eq` component

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       ...
       Values do not match:
         val refl : ('_a, '_a) eq
       is not included in
         val refl : ('a, 'a) eq
       File "lib/SO_typenoarg.ml", line 38, characters 2-24:
         Expected declaration
       File "lib/SO_typenoarg.ml", line 62, characters 6-10:
         Actual declaration
```

```ml
module Leibniz_ERROR : sig
  type ('a, 'b) eq

  val refl : ('a, 'a) eq
end = struct
  module type m = sig
    type 'a m
  end

  module type TyEq = sig
    type a
    type b
  end

  module Refl (X : sig
    type x
  end) : TyEq with type a = X.x and type b = X.x = struct
    type a = X.x
    type b = X.x
  end

  type ('a, 'b) eq = (module TyEq with type a = 'a and type b = 'b)

  module R = Refl (struct
    type x = int
  end)

  let refl (type a) : (a, a) eq =
    (module Refl (struct
      type x = a
    end))
end
```

It is solved (a bit mysteriously to me) by delaying `refl`

```ml
module Leibniz : sig
  type ('a, 'b) eq

  val refl : unit -> ('a, 'a) eq
end = struct
  module type m = sig
    type 'a m
  end

  module type TyEq = sig
    type a
    type b
  end

  module Refl (X : sig
    type x
  end) : TyEq with type a = X.x and type b = X.x = struct
    type a = X.x
    type b = X.x
  end

  type ('a, 'b) eq = (module TyEq with type a = 'a and type b = 'b)

  module R = Refl (struct
    type x = int
  end)

  let refl (type a) : unit -> (a, a) eq =
   fun _ ->
    (module Refl (struct
      type x = a
    end))
end
```

What's your practical rule of thumb for when to add a thunk ?

Answer (score 3):

It is called eta-expansion and it is done to turn a value (which could be anything including a closure that does some nasty stuff) into a syntactic value for which it is guaranteed that it is fully defined in static time (i.e., that it is not a computed question).

In other words, weak variables are introduced when a type variable doesn't have a ground type and it is ascribed to a value that is either non-syntactic (i.e., a result of computation) or to a value to which *the relaxed value restriction* doesn't apply. The relaxed value restriction part is rather interesting but convoluted. It allows generalization (turning type variables into polymorphic types) for values that are not syntactic constants. See this article for the [high-level overview of weak variables](https://ocamlverse.github.io/content/weak_type_variables.html) it has a part about the value restriction and its interaction with subtyping and covariance. And here's more [academic read](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf) on the topic.

Finally, your `eq` type could be easily defined without any computations using constant syntactic values, i.e., with the GADT, `type ('a,'b) eq = T : ('a,'a) eq`, e.g.,

```
module Leibniz : sig
  type ('a, 'b) eq

  val refl : ('a, 'a) eq
end = struct
  module type m = sig
    type 'a m
  end

  module type TyEq = sig
    type a
    type b
  end

  module Refl (X : sig
      type x
    end) : TyEq with type a = X.x and type b = X.x = struct
    type a = X.x
    type b = X.x
  end

  type ('a,'b) eq = T : ('a,'a) eq


  module R = Refl (struct
      type x = int
    end)

  let refl (type a) : (a, a) eq = T
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the value restriction at work

```ml
   (module Refl (struct
      type x = a
    end))
```

is a computation and not a syntactic value and it thus cannot be generalized by a let-binding.

Comment: I did not realize this was a computation as well ... are there famous case of computation happening upon functor application ? can we, say, trace functor application with it ?

Comment: No, it is just the type checker that assumes that everything that is not a part of the syntactic class of values and that is not subject to the value restriction relaxation rules, shall not be generalized. It has nothing to do with the nature of functors. A simple function will also have the same issue. See my answer for more details.